# I can not run any query on BigQuery anymore (transient error n°4233314)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I can no longer query nor preview nor run any job in BigQuery in our region (europe-west2/London).

When trying to run any query, I get the following error in the GCP Console:

> An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
> This is usually caused by a transient issue. Retrying the job with
> back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should solve the problem:
> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error continues to occur
> please contact support at https://cloud.google.com/support. Error:
> 4233314

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also receiving this error (same region, London).  I believe it is part of a wider outage which is also affecting firebase's firestore and cloud storage among other things

See this question:
[Firestore europe-west2 outage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73039765/firestore-europe-west2-outage)

https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/fmEL9i2fArADKawkZAa2#guoaCiLrsny92g8eoeyR